# Putting data into database table columns that are non-nullable and have NULL as the default value using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Introduction**

I want to input data into my database where I don't exactly know which columns I have to include in the INSERT query (because of the fact that some columns might be both NON-nullable and also have as default value NULL).

I'm using Dapper to insert the data into my database. My program flow is something like this:

1. User sends Json
2. I deserialize the Json into a C# object
3. I input the data in the deserialized Json into the database.

The problem is the user can't (or maybe just doesn't want to) send me the entire Json. For example, there might be a column in the database which contains the date at which the data was inserted into the database. The user can't send me this data in the Json, so I have to get it in the code and then insert that into the database along the data the user sent.

**This is what I want in SQL terms:**

```
INSERT 
INTO example_table (sent_by_user1, sent_by_user2, sent_by_user3, NOT_sent_by_user1, NOT_sent_by_user2)
VALUES ('example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'value_decided_in_code1', 'value_decided_in_code2')
```

NOT_sent_by_user1 and NOT_sent_by_user2 are the columns whose input I have to decide in the code.

I am able to do this manually if need be: I could just manually add the NOT_sent_by_userX stuff to the SQL query manually. But I would prefer not to do that since I may not know the structure of the table perfectly. I'm looking for a way that allows me to find out which columns are NON nullable with default value NULL and insert them into the SQL query dynamically (along with a default value I decide in the code).

**I thought of one way of accomplishing this that smells hacky:**

1. Run the following SQL command to get the columns that are NOT nullable and have as default value NULL (this is the step that seems hacky to me)

   ```sql
   SELECT * 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' and TABLE_NAME = 'example_table' and COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL;
   ```
2. Save the columns along with their data Types in a List of columns + Type.
3. Create a function that assigns a default value based on the type (so varchar gets 'default', int gets 0, and so on).
4. Put the columns along with their default values into the SQL query and query the database.

Are there any other ways of doing what I want that doesn't involve looking into the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table?

Comment: If the columns aren't `NULL`able, and aren't supplied, how do *you* know what value they should have `INSERT`ed?

Comment: As a separate note, SQL Server supports JSON data so do you *need* to deserialise is in your application?

Comment: [Build INSERT statment dynamically?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8M5FUg)

Comment: Why do you not know the columns you are inserting into, whether they are nullable or not? Seems pretty basic table design information, just look it up in SSMS. How do you know the column names or even the table name if you are doing it dynamically?

Comment: @Charlieface what I meant is that I that I don't want to find the column names manually because the structure of the table might change (which means I would have to rewrite the code). I'm looking for a way to get the column names that are non nullable and have a default value of null and build the SQL query using that information. I mentioned a way to do this in my post, but my solution feels a bit hacky, that's why I asked for alternative. Also, I should've mentioned this before, but I do know the name of the table a priori, I don't have to find that programatically.

Comment: Well I'd suggest you *do* write the column names manually, and if the structure changes then you change your code. That is the best way to guarantee that structure changes are followed through properly. "Are there any other ways of doing what I want that doesn't involve looking into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table?" No that's the only way, except that I'd recommend using `sys.columns` instead, because `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only. If the columns have defaults then you don't need to specify them *at all* in the SQL insert].

Comment: *"because the structure of the table might change"* and if it is changing, why are you not updating the application to reflect that? If the table's structure is changing and the application devs aren't being told to update the application then communication within the business is the *real* problem.

Comment: @ThomA I know what default values all those types of columns should have, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: *"I know what default values all those types of columns should have"* Then why are they not `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINTS`? Then you can just omit the column from the `INSERT`; easy peasy.

Comment: You're definititely overcomplicating this. Do you need columns to be not null? Why not make optional columns NULLable, and non-optional having default values, no need to code anything else. Or make everything NULL. You can always "fix" your column values when you actually read data from it. I'm voting for nullable all around though, especially for data coming from "outside"